# Is there way to convert mask image into UIBezierPath in iOS

Tags: ios, path, gradient, mask, uibezierpath

I wanted to show animations on parts of image like a coloring apps. I achieved this with masking but that is heavy on performance.

I'm looking a way to convert a mask into UIBezierPath so I can add animations on layers on UIView instead of UIView object every-time.

I'm trying to following the exact same method of 
[MagicWand for Mac](https://bitbucket.org/andyfinnell/magicwand)
but it has lot of Cocoa classes. Anyone can suggest me the solution of converting **mask or image to UIBezierPath** object according to iOS classes or any tutorial to find the clue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by mask? You have a PNG that is bundled in your app?

Comment: Mask is greyscale according to Apple doc. But I have an option to use PNG as mask if there is any solution?

Comment: If you have these image bundled in your app when you are shipping them, then there is no reason to do complex calculation on the phone.  You can simply use photoshop's magic wand and export a path.  But if these masks are created by the user you could not do this simple solution.

Comment: Agree with @Jon Rose. If you are using bundled mask - than convert it to svg and use it to calculate bezier paths. If not - ask your backend to send you svg mask.

Comment: Is this kind of effect you want add? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860055/ios-animate-mask-over-uiimage

Comment: Compositing with a travel matte should be pretty light weight, certainly lighter than rotoscoping the travel matte every frame and applying it to its own layer...

basically there should be one multiplication per pixel when you are blitting... and I suspect it is pretty easy to get that done at the opengl or metal layer.

how are you doing your masking?

Comment: I think this will make sense what I wanted to Achieve:
1 - Make a mask with code.
2 - Covert mask into bezier path.
3 - Animate bezier path real-time

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at [PocketSVG](https://github.com/pocketsvg/PocketSVG) if you are ok with using SVGs for the images. You'd get an array of bezier paths for a given svg. You could add each of these paths as separate CAShapeLayer objects and add any animations to their path and fill color as intended using CABasicAnimation.

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way I can use same technique for PNGs/JPGs. I can't use SVGs right now because we have same backend for iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

Code.org has a thing called the app lab were you can use colors and designs to edit with code.