# How to create a circular loader from an image in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I've done a bit of research but unfortunately only found some libraries that allowed coloured circular loaders and not using an image.

So here's my issue, I've got a circular countdown which in the design I've got to implement uses a complex glow that I find really hard to reproduce as shown. The progress of this countdown is shown by this glow progressing over 3 seconds around a circle.

My initial thought was to try to modify UIView+Glow so that the glow wouldn't vary but even then I would come at a stop when it came to making my UIView radially hidden.

So I'm now thinking of simply exporting the outer glow that makes the progress bar as an image and radially hiding that (which would be faster and simpler to do in the end, rather than trying to make the exact same glow manually).

Does anyone have any idea where I should start looking or what I should be doing to hide part of a circular image using angles/rads ?

EDIT: here's what the glow looks like overlayed with the circular label (the black circle) that is used to show the countdown value.

[image]

Comment: Do include the code that you have tried so far

Comment: @Carpsen90 I haven't tried code yet because none of the libraries I found even allowed use of images for circular loaders, at this stage I've done research for it but I've got inconclusive results. I'm looking for some guidance of where to look to be able to do what I'm looking to do. I don't usually like to start trying to code something without a minimum of planning ahead which is why I mainly focused on my train of thought here rather than the code. I am not looking only for a direct answer here, a valid train of thought would be just as useful to implement as long as I know what to use.

Comment: I've noticed that UIBezierPath could be used for the coloured circular loader, but I don't know if I can use this to radially hide an image and animate that as well. If I'm really going to be investing time in trying to use UIBezierPath (which i've never used before directly) for this purpose then I'd at least like to know from someone who knows what they're talking about that it isn't a huge waste of time for me to do so.

Comment: Maybe should showing some code or some images of the desired effect could help us help you

Comment: @Carpsen90 I've added the desired effect I retrieved from the designs I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would like to thank @Carpsen90 for helping me out, although his answer was not what I was looking for it helped me understand how to use `CABasicAnimation` and in combination with inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29860191/4350037) I found a solution to my problem using an image and a `CAShapeLayer`

for those wondering what I did here's the code I used

```swift
// countdownGlow is the glow (white and red part of my image)
func animateMask() {
        let arcPath = CGMutablePath()
        arcPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: self.countdownGlow.frame.width / 2, y: 0))
        arcPath.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: self.countdownGlow.frame.width / 2, y: self.countdownGlow.frame.width / 2), radius: self.countdownGlow.frame.width / 2, startAngle: CGFloat(-1 * Double.pi / 2), endAngle: CGFloat(-3 * Double.pi / 2), clockwise: false)
        arcPath.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: self.countdownGlow.frame.width / 2, y: self.countdownGlow.frame.width / 2), radius: self.countdownGlow.frame.width / 2, startAngle: CGFloat(-3 * Double.pi / 2), endAngle: CGFloat(-5 * Double.pi / 2), clockwise: false)
        let ringLayer = CAShapeLayer(layer: self.countdownGlow.layer)
        ringLayer.path = arcPath
        
        ringLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0
        ringLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        ringLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        ringLayer.lineWidth = self.countdownGlow.frame.width / 2
        
        self.countdownGlow.layer.mask = ringLayer
        self.countdownGlow.layer.mask?.frame = self.countdownGlow.layer.bounds
        
        let swipe = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        swipe.duration = 3
        swipe.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
        swipe.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        swipe.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
        swipe.toValue = 1.0
        ringLayer.add(swipe, forKey: "strokeEnd")
}
```

I couldn't seem to simply tell my arc to be a full circle so I went with half a circle once and then another half circle which worked out

If you have any improvements to offer I would gladly try it out to see, because I am sure my solution is not optimised at all